# React hover animation based on class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've asked a few questions so far regarding this component and hovering. My next and final question is regarding animation on hover.

I have the default class called .eye-container & and then .eye-container-hover

What is the best way to animate this transition on hover. Here is my Item component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import Eyecon from '../../static/eye.svg';


class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.displayName = 'Item';
        this.state = {
            hover: false
        };
    }
    mouseOver(){
        this.setState({hover: true});
    }
    mouseOut() {
        this.setState({hover: false});
    }
    render() {
      const { item, i } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="grid-box" onMouseOver={this.mouseOver.bind(this)} onMouseOut={this.mouseOut.bind(this)}>
                <Link to={`/view/${item.id}`}>
                    <div className="eye-container">
                        <img src={Eyecon}/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="grid-image">
                        <img src={item.image} alt="" className="fade-in img"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="columns">
                        <div className="column">
                            <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="column">
                            <h3>Type:</h3>
                            <p>{item.type}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Item;
```

This is my "get-to-know-react" project. Hope someone can help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with the hover effect? Would a standard CSS `:hover` pseudo-class be sufficient?

Comment: @TimoSta I want to change the position, z-index, and height.

Comment: This can be achieved purely with the CSS's [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). This allows you to significantly declutter your JavaScript code.

Comment: @TimoSta but I'm trying to effect the .eye-container class

Comment: And this does not work because ...?

Comment: @TimoSta if I have for example .grid-box:hover {} how would I change the height and z-index of .eye-container?

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be solved much simpler and cleaner using pure CSS and its `:hover` pseudo-class: (hit the *Run code snippet* button)

```css
.blackbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.blackbox:hover {
  z-index: 3;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.redbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='blackbox'></div>
  <div class='redbox'></div>
<div>
```

**Edit:** You can also change e.g. the element's siblings using the right CSS selectors:

```css
.blackbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.blackbox:hover + div {
  z-index: 0;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.redbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 70px;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='blackbox'></div>
  <div class='redbox'></div>
<div>
```

Comment: How would you hover over the black box and animate the red box?

Comment: It works in the snippet but won't work for me. This is what I used.   .grid-box:hover + .eye-container {
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
  }

Comment: eye-container isn't a child of grid-box.

Comment: This is because the `+` selector refers to the direct sibling of the element. The two elements you are trying to connect are no siblings.

Comment: @TimoSta Can I control the duration of the animation ? Can the animation happen slowly using css ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use pure CSS, if you have no dependency interactions. By this I mean
- You don't have any synchronise interactions that trigger before or after the animation
- You animation is purely CSS based, no JS required.

You can use react to add/remove hover class to the element, which gives a bit more control over the animation.

```
.eye {}
.eyeContainer.lookAround .eye{ ..animate.. }
.eyeContainer.blink .eyelid {} // you can do a timer to change its state
```

And i would suggest you use the classnames module, so that you can use state to change the class like, and contains all css in the same component, so you don't have multiple files to manage

```
<eye className={classnames({
         blink: this.state.blink,
         rotate : this.state.rotate
})} />
```

or just pure css for simplicity

```
.eye {
    z-index:1;

}
.eye:hover + .eyelid.blink{
    z-index:10
    height: 0
    animate: height 2s
}
```